# requested datatype filelists not available in yum update

Tags: repository, artifactory, patch, yum, rhel7

In order to patch RedHat 7 machines to version 7.9, I've created an RPM repository with RPMs extracted from a DVD.iso file of the patch ([example source guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/deployment_guide/s1-yum-upgrade-system)), and updated said machines using yum.
The patch has succeeded with many of the machines (RHEL 7.7 only), but the rest (7.0, 7.2 and some 7.7 as well) have failed the with the following error:

**Error: requested datatype filelists not available**

I've also tried to gradualize the process and patch the 7.0 and 7.2 ones to 7.7 first by the same process, but yielded the same result. I've made sure I got each and every file in the Packages folder.
It is rather puzzling for me that some succeed and some fail, especially those with the same version. But I'm assuming they were created differently as I don't have the information to say otherwise. So my best direction would be to go by the error.

In [this github post](https://github.com/ankane/pghero/issues/133), **lr1980** says:

> https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2015/07/20/yum-repository-internals/
> this means the "filelists.xml.gz" is missing on repo => it's a packager.io problem

Indeed, browsing my repository's repodata folder reveals only other.xml.gz and primary.xml.gz files, which are also the only files pointed to in the repomd.xml.
I've tried uploading the filelists.xml.gz file from the dvd.iso and reindexing, but it gets removed (admittedly am not familiar with this area of knowledge.. at all). What does "it's a packager.io problem" mean?

How can I force the repo to have such a file, assuming that's what I need? Or what can I do to solve this issue otherwise?

Many thanks